# How can someone upload a container and run it on my Docker server?

Tags: windows, docker, ubuntu, containers, hosting

I have docker running on a server. How can someone now upload their container to my server and if it's a website, deposit a domain?

Is there any "easy" way?
When I google I only come across results from the Docker cloud

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options; first one is to share ssh credentials of your machine (docker). Second option is to give them the credential of the server itself so he could access server then access docker from your server by exposing a port.

Comment: So docker is not such a good idea for hosting multiple websites from multiple users?

Comment: I personally do not recommend that; it is so much pain in managing resources, accessing and if something goes wrong with one website would easily affects the other.

Comment: Do you know something else?

Comment: technically, adding users to your machine so people upload their containers and running their containers.